# htaccess to redirect dynamic urls to new directory

Tags: .htaccess

I have a PhpBB3.2 forum on my domain in the directory named forum:
http://www.domain.com/forum/

I want to move the forum to http://www.domain.com/ (in the root), but I also want to keep external and internal old links to keep working. How can I redirect the following URL to its new location?

http://domain.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&p=384901
to
http://domain.com/viewtopic.php?f=4&p=384901

Kind regards,

Daniel

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rule as **first rule in `forum/.htaccess` file**:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule .* /$0 [L,NE,R=301]
```